# Body resized using jQuery, how to do I make children resize too?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery to adjust the height of the body so it fills the visible space without scroll bars appearing (as they do while using height:100%).

The following function is ran on document ready and window resize:

```
function padBody() {
  var viewPort = $('html').height();
  var navHeight = $('#master_navbar').height();
  var footerHeight = $('#master_footer').height();
  $('body').css('padding-top', navHeight +"px");
  $('body').css('min-height', (viewPort - footerHeight) + "px");
}
```

However the child divs inside body which are set to height:100% do not resize when the body's height it changed.

How can I get the other divs to redraw using the new body height?

Comment: Have you tryed using css 100vh?

Comment: I think 100vh will work. can you tried as suggested by @NicholasO'Malley

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the main content div fill height of screen with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665171/how-to-make-the-main-content-div-fill-height-of-screen-with-css)

Comment: The [third answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27574060/4076315) is the one you want.